# Regular expression to get particular class name from a tag in php

Tags: php, regex, joomla2.5

[image]I want to get a tag from the string/content matching class name "coremetrics" using regular expression

In Content href will be avilable like this `<a href="/children" class="hp2s_desc_btn hp_sp13_btn_2 coremetrics">`

I need to get the a tag (red boxed) in an array using indetifier class name "coremetrics" (black box)

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: What tag do you want.

Comment: a href tag fully. @Basic Bridge

Comment: I need to get the a href tags using indetifier class name "coremetrics" @Nicholas Pickering

Comment: Have a look at this [QueryPath soluion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394657/using-multiple-find-in-foreach-with-querypath). It allows searching for css selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this regex
`<a(.+)?class="(.+)?coremetrics">`
Demo link http://regex101.com/r/xQ6dR8

Second regex `<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?class=".*?coremetrics.*?"[^>]*>`

if you use this php code

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?class=".*?coremetrics.*?"[^>]*>/', '<a href="yoursite.com" class="hp2s_desc_btn hp_sp13_btn_2 coremetrics">', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

you get arry like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="yoursite.com" class="hp2s_desc_btn hp_sp13_btn_2 coremetrics">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => yoursite.com
        )

)
```

use `echo $matches[1][0];` to echo out the href value

Comment: im using $link ='/<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s'; but in that i need to add one more checkpoint class name "coremetrics". Can you edit this reg expression for me @Basic Bridge

Comment: @Ashlash this might help `<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?class=".*?coremetrics.*?"[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve all links that are of class "coremetrics" then I would recommend you to do this with XPath.

Use this expression when querying: `//a[contains(@class, 'coremetrics')]`

Answer (score 0):

checkout: http://php.net/manual/pl/class.domxpath.php much easier to manipulate DOM tree than with regex way..